# How to get the result of the camera callback on html div, img,

Tags: android, cordova, callback, camera

It´s possible to get the camera result callback data into a html div or img or whatever with Phonegap?

For example to see on a div what the camera is seeing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see the camera API docs [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.6.1/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera). Load the Full Example. The Capture Photo button displays the taken picture in a div.